# Restangular, is it possible to do a Post without a previous reading?

Tags: restangular

In the documentation's examples, each POST is preceded by a reading, is it possible to do a Post without this previous step?

Bye,
Hervé

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restangular need to know to which resource you are going to post, this is a required step, otherwise it won't be able to generate the url.

To not get data, you just need to not use `get()` or `getList()` methods.

So any of those should work :

```js
var account = Restangular.service("accounts");
account.post({data});

var account Restangular.oneUrl('googlers', 'http://www.google.com/1');
account.post({data});

// the 'one()' method will allow you to use 'account.save()' later which will decide to POST or PUT accordingly
var account = Restangular.one("accounts");
account.post({data});
```